# ImportXML XPath issue using Google Sheets on a simple web scraping query

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've been trying with no success to importxml using google sheets to scrape the Advanced Receiving table data from the url https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201912290car.htm.

I've tried the XPath copied directly from the inspect chrome page of: `//*[@id="div_receiving_advanced"]`
where I always get the "Imported content is empty" error message.

I'm stumped because it works with the Passing, Rushing, & Receiving table data using the XPath of: `//*[@id="div_player_offense"]`

When I use the XPath of: `//*[@id="all_receiving_advanced"]`, I get the following results.

[unparsed results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkgOs.png)

However, I'd like to parse the data from the 2nd column so it looks like this.

[parsed results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaVD8.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since some players don't have value for specific columns (for eg : "Rec/Br"), transforming directly the data returned by `IMPORTXML` will produce a scrambled table.

2 solutions  :

**A)** Use `IMPORTFROMWEB` [addon](https://nodatanobusiness.com/importfromweb/) (number of requests are limited in the free plan) with JS rendering activated and a base selector option to keep the data structure. XPath expressions needed for data :

```
/th/a
/td[@data-stat="team"]
/td[@data-stat="targets"]
/td[@data-stat="rec"]
/td[@data-stat="rec_yds"]
/td[@data-stat="rec_first_down"]
/td[@data-stat="rec_air_yds"]
/td[@data-stat="rec_air_yds_per_rec"]
/td[@data-stat="rec_yac"]   
/td[@data-stat="rec_yac_per_rec"]   
/td[@data-stat="rec_broken_tackles"]    
/td[@data-stat="rec_broken_tackles_per_rec"]    
/td[@data-stat="rec_drops"] 
/td[@data-stat="rec_drop_pct"]
```

for the headers :

```
//div[@id="div_receiving_advanced"]//th[contains(@class,"poptip")]
```

for the base selector :

```
//div[@id="div_defense_advanced"]//tr[@data-row][not(@class)]
```

Formula used in C6 :

```
IMPORTFROMWEB(B1;B2:O2;B3:C4)
```

Output :

[image: IFWrev2f]

Side note : `IMPORTFROMWEB` often output loading errors.

**B)** Use `IMPORTDATA` and formulas to generate the table. First we load the data of interest with a filter (`QUERY`). Then we fix the blank cells problem with `SUBSTITUTE`. After that we extract the data with `REGEXEXTRACT`. Finally we apply a last filter and `SPLIT` the data to populate the cells.

Formula :

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(IMPORTDATA(B3);"select Col1 where Col1 contains 'rec_broken_tackles_per_rec'");"></td>";">0</td>"));".+htm.+?>(.+?)<.+team.+([A-Z]{3}).+targets.+?>(.+?)<.+?rec.+?>(.+?)<.+?rec.+?>(.+?)<.+?rec.+?>(.+?)<.+?rec.+?>(.+?)<.+?rec.+?>(.+?)<.+?rec.+?>(.+?)<.+?rec.+?>(.+?)<.+?rec.+?>(.+?)<.+?rec.+?>(.+?)<.+?rec.+?>(.+?)<.+?rec.+?>(.+?)<.+";"$1;$2;$3;$4;$5;$6;$7;$8;$9;$10;$11;$12;$13;$14"));"select * WHERE NOT Col1 contains '<'");";"))
```

Output :

[image: IDATA]

In both cases, blank cells are replaced with `0`.

[image: Blank]

My working workbook is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/188ymkaujz-afB1muLUr2QBig9LMvg2CeWVGVci4B3rs/edit?usp=sharing).

**EDIT :**

For "Advanced Defense Table" with `IMPORTDATA` :

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(IMPORTDATA(B3);"select Col1 where Col1 contains 'def_tgt_yds_per_att'");"></td>";">0</td>"));".+htm.+?>(.+?)<.+team.+([A-Z]{3})<.+?def.+?>(.+?)<.+?def.+?>(.+?)<.+?def.+?>(.+?)<.+?def.+?>(.+?)<.+?def.+?>(.+?)<.+?def.+?>(.+?)<.+?def.+?>(.+?)<.+?def.+?>(.+?)<.+?def.+?>(.+?)<.+?def.+?>(.+?)<.+?def.+?>(.+?)<.+?def.+?>(.+?)<.+?bli.+?>(.+?)<.+?qb_.+?>(.+?)<.+?qb_.+?>(.+?)<.+?sac.+?>(.+?)<.+?pre.+?>(.+?)<.+?tac.+?>(.+?)<.+?tac.+?>(.+?)<.+?tac.+?>(.+?)<.+";"$1;$2;$3;$4;$5;$6;$7;$8;$9;$10;$11;$12;$13;$14;$15;$16;$17;$18;$19;$20;$21;$22"));"select * WHERE NOT Col1 contains '<'");";"))
```

Output :

[image: ADT]

Comment: E. - Thanks for providing two (2) great alternatives. Does the IMPORTFROMWEB function have a cap of 15 xpaths? I tried to use this command against the Advanced Defense table and got an error. It works if I limit the number of xpaths to 15 but fails for anything greater. Could you share the IMPORTDATA solution for the Advanced Defense table? I tried to modify the one used for receiving table with no success.

Comment: I don't think it's a cap but yes, try to limit the number of XPath in your `IMPORTFROMWEB` formula. Otherwise you'll get timeout errors.
So, for the "Advanced Defense Table", use 2 `IMPORTFROMWEB` formulas. Post have been updated with a formula if you choose `IMPORTDATA` option for "Advanced Defense Table". Workbook is also updated. `IMPORTFROMWEB` formulas has been optimized a bit (better baseSelector). Cell with yellow background contain formulas.

Comment: And of course, if your problem is solved please mark my post as best answer.